# Equationtrekker is not giving plots

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, packages

Just a quick question, I need to draw some phase plots via Mathematica and saw the application equation trekker. This seemed helpful and legit from a Mathematica website however when I tried to apply it, it doesn't give any plots what so ever.

The code that I run is displayed under here. It opens the display form but there are no plots can't edit anything

I am using Mathematica 12.1.1 and Windows 10

<< EquationTrekker`

%This runs fine%

EquationTrekker[y''[x] + 2*y[x] == 0, y, {x, 0, Pi}]

**Errors given:**

PropertyValue::pvobj: canvas is not an object with properties.
PropertyValue::pvobj: trekPane is not an object with properties.
PropertyValue::poi: -- Message text not found -- (PropertyValue[{canvas,canvasPane,All},Name->trekPane]) (1)
PropertyValue::poi: -- Message text not found -- (PropertyValue[{trekPane,trekController,All},Name->trekController]) (1)

**If somebody could enlighten me with some help that would be great!**

Comment: This is a very old, unmaintained package that I expect might be removed from Mathematica in the future (many other old standard packages have already been removed). I would not spend too much time on trying to get it working in recent Mathematica versions.